# How to convert milliseconds to a date string?

Tags: javascript, date, time

I get a miliseconds string from the server like this: 1345623261.

How can i convert this into a normal date format, e.g. 30.08.2012?

I attempted using `setMilliseconds`, like so:

```js
new Date().setMilliseconds(time_posted).toLocaleString();
```

But this doesn't work. How to do that?

Answer (score 23):

Assuming `time_posted` is a number representing timestamp, which is expressed in seconds (judging by the number of digits) - multiply it by 1000 to get a representation in  milliseconds, and pass the result to the `Date`'s constructor:

```js
(new Date(time_posted * 1000)).toLocaleString();
    // -> "Wed Aug 22 2012 11:14:21 GMT+0300 (Jerusalem Daylight Time)"
```

To take this a bit further and achieve something closer to what you denoted in the question, use `toLocaleDateString()`, which will produce a more human-readable form:

```js
(new Date(time_posted * 1000)).toLocaleDateString();
    // -> "Wednesday, August 22, 2012"
```

#### Reference

- [`Date` on Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)