# How can I convert milliseconds to date and time string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

can I convert milliseconds to date and time string. suppose I have millisecond in a long number and I want it like this:
Oct 22 2013 09:50:17
is this possible??

Comment: here you go: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4673527/converting-milliseconds-to-a-date-jquery-js, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8579861/how-to-convert-milliseconds-into-a-readable-date, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12196689/how-to-convert-milliseconds-to-a-date-string, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12435403/convert-datetime-to-milliseconds

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
var date = new Date(1324339212260);
date.toString("MMM dd");
```